Confusion over Riemann's prime counting function
I'm trying to get my head around Riemann's prime counting function, given here (equation 3) as
$$f\left(x\right)=\pi\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\pi\left(x^{1/2}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\pi\left(x^{1/3}\right)+\ldots$$ Excuse my confusion, but how can a prime counting function include on the rhs the very thing it is supposed to count, ie the $\pi\left(x\right)$ term? If we know $\pi\left(x\right)$,why do we need $f\left(x\right)$?

It doesn't count just primes, to be fair; it's also accounting for powers and such. Wikipedia suggests it is defined this way to have log-zeta as its Mellin transform.
